# How to fix: Golang "append" method pushing same elements to slice

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to map data from DB ( Mongo ) to slice in go , and everythin works fine if I'm returning simple `[]string` but if I change type to `[]*models.Organization` that code returns slice of same elements.

```golang
func (os *OrganizationService) GetAll() ([]*models.Organization, error) {
    var organizations []*models.Organization
    results := os.MongoClient.Collection("organizations").Find(bson.M{})
    organization := &models.Organization{}
    for results.Next(organization) {
        fmt.Println(organization)
        organizations = append(organizations, organization)
    }
    return organizations, nil
}
```

I expect output `[{ Name: "someOrg", ID: "someId" },{ Name: "someOrg2", ID: "someID }, ... ]` , but actual output is  `[{ Name: "someOrg", ID: "someId" },{ Name: "someOrg", ID: "someId" }, ... ]`

I'm using `bongo` package.

Comment: Look at the https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver#usage. You need to pass a context to results.Next(ctx) and call `results.Decode(&organzation)` and the print/append.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response but that's can't help me becouse I'm using `bongo` to connect with mongoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application appends the same value of `organization` on every iteration through the loop. Fix by creating a new value inside the loop.

```
func (os *OrganizationService) GetAll() ([]*models.Organization, error) {
    var organizations []*models.Organization
    results := os.MongoClient.Collection("organizations").Find(bson.M{})
    organization := &models.Organization{}
    for results.Next(organization) {
        fmt.Println(organization)
        organizations = append(organizations, organization)
        organization = &models.Organization{} // new value for next iteration
    }
    return organizations, nil
}
```